# Push Notifications. How to know if the app was in foreground or background

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When a notification arrives the app executes the callback configured for receiving the notifications.

In case the notification arrives with the app in background I want the application to move to a specific view. But if the notification arrives with the app in foreground I just want to print an alert.

How can I know in the callback function the status of the application when the notification arrived?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how dependable this is, but it seems to work when the app is running, but just in the background:

```
var sleeping = false;

document.addEventListener("pause", function() {sleeping = true;}, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {sleeping = false;}, false);
```

and then:

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    if (sleeping) {

        alert("caught me napping");

    } else {

        alert("I've been waiting for you.");
    }
}
```

The tricky case is when the application is completely stopped.  You need to log in before the notification callback gets called, and the resume event is fired long before this.  If you want to handle that case, you will probably need something like the following in your WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe function:

```
sleeping = true;
setTimeout(function(){sleeping = false;}, 1000);
```

(anything that arrives within 1 second of being ready to subscribe, probably arrived when we were asleep, and is just getting delivered now)

It is a bit of a haCk, and I'm sure there are all sorts of odd timing cases but it seems to cover many of the cases.

Comment: Hi. Did you test it? I have put traces and (in iPad) when the notification arrives the first thing the application does is to update the sleepling value to false and then execute the pushNotificationReceived.

Comment: Yes, As I said, I don't know how dependable it is … it depends on the ordering of asynchonous actions.  But in my testing, the above solution worked.  I was testing on Android, so maybe that is the difference.  You could change the resume callback to use the setTimeout (as is done for the onReadyToSubscribe above)  Not pretty.  More of a workaround than a solution.